# UINavigationController title view truncates briefly when moving from view with smaller font to larger font

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

My root view on a `UINavigationController` has a title with a font point size of 36.  I perform a push segue to a view where the navigation bar title has a font size of 24 (the title is a longer string).  I'm setting the font size for each view with `setTitleTextAttributes:` in `viewWillAppear:` and the change in font size is made (from larger font to smaller font.

The problem is that when I go back to the root view, the title will briefly be truncated before increasing the size to 36.

[image: Nav Bar]

I'm setting the title strings in a Storyboard.  All I really need to change is the font size between some views.  Is there a way to correct this without creating a new title label for each view?